# wicked pdf custom font doesn't load properly in Rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

i'm trying to import a custom font on a PDF
my fonts are in `/public` folder at the root of my app

i'm importing fonts this way

```
<style type="text/css">

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Circular';
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("<%= Rails.root.join('public', 'CircularStd-Book.otf') %>") format('otf');
    font-style: normal;
  }

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Circular';
    src: url("<%= Rails.root.join('public', 'CircularStd-Bold.otf') %>") format('otf');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Circular';
    src: url("<%= Rails.root.join('public', 'CircularStd-Medium.otf') %>") format('otf');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
  }

  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Circular' sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 1403px; /*297mm*/
    height: 991.5px; /*210mm*/
  }
</style>
```

here is how it renders

[image]

and this is what it should be

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use asset_data_base64 for font src

`src: url(asset_data_base64('CircularStd-Book.otf')) format('otf');`

https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/334#issuecomment-82637728

Comment: unfortunatly it said `undefined method asset_data_base64 ....` 
i tried to use `wicked_pdf_asset_base64('CircularStd-Book.otf')` > `uninitialized constant WickedPdf::WickedPdfHelper::Assets::Sprockets`